# How to display images from List

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display my list of images from class ImageS. I can read images in the console.

```
class ImageS with ChangeNotifier {
final String id;
final List<String> image;

ImageS({
this.id,
this.image,
});
}
class ImagesProvider with ChangeNotifier {
List<ImageS> _items = [];
List<ImageS> get items {

return [..._items];
}
Future<void> fetchAndSetImages() async {

var url = 'https://project-d4677.firebaseio.com/images.json';
try {
  final response = await http.get(url);
  print('class ImagesProvider, ${json.decode(response.body)}');
  final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  if(extractedData==null){
    return;
  }

  final List<ImageS> loadedList = [];
  print('ImagesProvider ${loadedList.toList().length}'); //a list of images is displayed in the 
  //console
  extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
    loadedList.add(       
      Images(
        id: prodId,
        image: prodData['image'].cast<String>(),

      ),

    );

  });
  _items = loadedList;
  notifyListeners();
} catch (error) {
  throw (error);
}
}

Future<void> dodajImages(Images img, List<String> imagess) async {
final url = 'https://project-d4677.firebaseio.com/images.json';

try {
  final response = await http.post(
    url,
      body: json.encode({

        'image':  imagess
      }) 
      );

  final noviProizvod = Images(
    id: json.decode(response.body)['name'],
    image: imagess,

  );

  _items.insert(0, newProd); 
  notifyListeners();
} catch (error) {
  print(error);
  throw (error);
} 
}
}
```

In my class `ImagesWidget` I try to display images. I tried different ways to display the pictures, but I'm unable to find a sufficient way that working in order to fetch the data. I keep getting constant errors.

```
class ImagesWidget extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_ImagesWidgetState createState() => _ImagesWidgetState();
}

class _ImagesWidgetState extends State<ImagesWidget> {
bool _isInit = true;
@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
// TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
super.didChangeDependencies();
if (_isInit) {
  Provider.of<ImagesProvider>(context).fetchAndSetImages();
}
_isInit = false;
}
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 final galery = Provider.of<ImageS>(context);
 GridView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 3,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 8,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return 
                    Stack(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Image.memory(
                          base64Decode(galery[index])//?????????????
                          // fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },

                  itemCount: galery.image.length,
                );
```

Comment: What type of errors? and what you are getting in galery[index]?

Comment: when I try to read galery.image[index].toString() Error: Could not find the correct Provider<ImageS> above this ImagesWidget Widget

Comment: Is this your complete code above?

Comment: It's compete for reading data/images

Comment: Can you post the complete class of ImagesWidget ?

Comment: class of ImagesWidget now is compete

Comment: Why you need to use Providers? any specific reason?

Comment: I need access to anathor class with provider to write the data. Please help me with your better access?